# What is the shortcut to switch the format of list from row to column in yaml file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, yaml, keyboard-shortcuts

I was stuck with the shortcut for formatting a YAML list in VS code. Before, the data list showed the elements in a row. But after I pressed some button from keyboard by mistake, the elements are now listed in a column. I wonder what button I have pressed, so I tried to search through the Keyboard Shortcuts but still could not find that.
It would be great if anyone knows the "secret" there!

See pic below:
[Before and after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkGF6.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: In the attached pic I show the different displays of the yaml list. One is shown as a row, while the other is shown as a column, with each element in the list shown in a row. I do not know how to switch between the two forms of display.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I figure this out by chance. The "before" one, which is displayed in row, is not formatted yet. If you right click and choose "Format Document", then the row-display will be converted into column-display. I think the column-display is the correct version in VS code. You can only "redo" to get back to the row-display version.
I got the row-display version after I ran the ck2yaml.py to convert a CHEMKIN mechanism to the one used in Cantera. I guess that is not automatically formatted so I got the row-display of the list.